# How can I adjust this query to get my intended results?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php include "includes/connect.php";
$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE
Gender LIKE 'female'
&& Travel LIKE 'yes'
OR Hiking LIKE 'yes'");
```

Name--------Gender-------Travel--------Hiking

Joe------------male-----------yes-----------yes
 Mary----------female---------yes-----------yes
 Jane----------female---------no------------yes
  Results:

Joe
 Mary
Jane

I am looking for results:

Mary
Jane

Update: I want the query to check if the user is a female who likes travel or hiking then return.
Update: Answered. Thanks everybody :)

```
SELECT * FROM users 
 WHERE Gender = 'female'
   AND ( Travel = 'yes'
      OR Hiking = 'yes')
```

Comment: It should be `Gender LIKE '%female%'` or `Gender='female'`. What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: `&&` should probably be `AND`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just say where Gender='female' AND Travel = 'yes' OR Hiking = 'yes'?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE
Gender LIKE '%female%'
AND Travel LIKE '%yes%'
OR Hiking LIKE '%yes%'
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is sort your result you can do this

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE Gender = 'female'
    AND (Travel = 'yes' OR Hiking = 'yes')
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, AND has higher [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html) than OR, so (aside from the errors others have mentioned)

```
SELECT * FROM users 
 WHERE Gender = 'female'
   AND Travel = 'yes'
    OR Hiking = 'yes'
```

is the equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM users 
 WHERE ( Gender = 'female'
     AND Travel = 'yes')
    OR Hiking = 'yes'
```

So you're searching for females who like travel OR anybody who likes hiking

If you're looking for females who like Travel OR females who like Hiking, use

```
SELECT * FROM users 
 WHERE Gender = 'female'
   AND ( Travel = 'yes'
      OR Hiking = 'yes')
```